# Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#

Tags: c#, json, faq, json.net, словари

Есть ответ с сервера в виде json:

```
{
  "14.05.2018": {
    "Min": "2",
    "Max": "7"
  },
  "15.05.2018": {
    "Min": "1",
    "Max": "7"
  }
}
```

Нужно распарсить в C# по уму. Я так понимаю это двумерный ассоциативный массив.

Подскажите как быть. Сам новичок в этом деле и ранее с json не работал.

Comment: В C# для этого есть словарь `Dictionary`

Comment: По-моему это самый типовой вопрос по json, на него уже несколько раз отвечали. Впору писать эталонную закрывашку и в FAQ выносить.

Comment: Используешь например библиотеку newtonsoft. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(json)`. Где Data класс с полями max,min.

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829577/218063

Comment: @adrug, соглашайтесь, плюсики всю оставшуюся жизнь будете собирать ;)

Comment: Хоть и стараюсь отвечать в вопросах с json, но не ради плюсиков. Да и не в них счастье. Здесь думаю нужно сделать ответ более развернутый, как это сделать делает пользователь EvgeniyZ.

Comment: @AK Вроде все расписал как надо. Если что, дайте знать, подправлю.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Мне нравится. Через пару дней открою конкурс, возможно вам будет ещё обратная связь от читающих ответ.

Comment: @AK Если вопрос канонический, зачем в нем "Всем привет!"? И зачем ссылки на похожие вопросы в начале, а не в конце?

Comment: Наверно нет смысла копипастить свои же ответы из других аналогичных вопросов :D

Comment: @АндрейNOP вопросы заданы в один день, но этот выглядит красивше

Answer (score 30):

### Подготовка

Давайте разберемся, что из себя вообще представляет ваш JSON. Я лично для подобных целей использую данный [ресурс](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu). Вставляем туда наши данные и видим следующую картину:

[image: JsonView]

Что тут у нас?

- У нас есть первый уровень (назовем его Root).

  - Root содержит в себе некие объекты, которые имеют название и что то внутри, (внутренние объекты назовем к примеру Data) .

    - Внутри Data мы видим два значения (min и max).

Хорошо, со структурой разобрались, дальше нам понадобится то, что облегчит нам жизнь при работе с JSON форматом, я лично рекомендую использовать [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), отличная библиотека для работы с JSON!

### Десериализация

Разобравшись со структурой и установив необходимое, можно приступать к десериализации (преобразования JSON в объект).

- Пойдем с самого конца, а именно создадим для начала Data. Мы помним, что Data имеет в себе 2 значения min и max, оба содержат число (то есть int). Имея все это, мы можем написать следующий класс:

  ```
  public class Data
  {
      public int Min { get; set; }
      public int Max { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Заметьте, все переменные здесь написаны по правилам CamelCase, то есть с большой буквы. Советую и вам придерживаться этого стиля при написании подобных классов, но нужно помнить: поменять регистр в названии можно без проблем, но если имя в классе будет отличаться от того, что в JSON — мы не получим данные и по этому подобные переименования стоит помечать атрибутом `[JsonProperty("oldName")]` с указанием имени, который есть в JSON.

- Так, имея класс Data, мы можем пойти уровнем выше, создать объект с именем и Data внутри. Для этого в C# принято использовать Dictionary (словарь), где Key — это будет имя (в вашем случае дата), а Value — данные (в вашем случае — класс Data). Исходя из этого мы можем написать следующее:

  ```
  var source = "{\"14.05.2018\":{\"min\":\"2\",\"max\":\"7\"},\"15.05.2018\":{\"min\":\"1\",\"max\":\"7\"}}";
  var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(source);
  ```

Поясню, мы вызываем метод DeserializeObject, которому задаем тип данных `Dictionary<string, Data>`, ну и передаем source — наш JSON в виде string.

Собственно и все, результатом мы получим объект `Dictionary<string, Data>` из которого можно получить то, что нам нужно, к примеру так:

```
parsed["14.05.2018"].Max;
```

Или пройтись циклом:

```
foreach (var data in parsed)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {data.Key}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Max: {data.Value.Max} Min: {data.Value.Min}");
}
```

Сам же объект parsed будем иметь примерно следующую структуру:

[image: Result]

Кстати! Для работы с JSON очень круто помогают ресурсы, которые сами за вас составляют нужную структуру классов, к примеру [этот](https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp). Вставив ваш JSON в левое поле и указав в поле Name желаемое имя класса (`Data`), сайт составит нам следующую структуру:

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("min")]
    public string Min { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("max")]
    public string Max { get; set; }
}

public partial class Data
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Data> FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}
```

Не напоминает ничего? В общем пользуйтесь, вещь очень полезная!
Надеюсь помог. Удачи в изучении C#!

Comment: В студии есть встроенный инструмент для перевода json в классы: `Edit` -> `Paste special` -> `Paste JSON as classes`

Comment: @Grundy Я не считаю этот функционал хорошим. К примеру JSON указав json из вопроса - выдало [это](https://hastebin.com/wusipewoma.vbs)

Answer (score 6):

Как вам уже предложили в комментариях к вопросу, если вам нужен ассоциативный массив - его и используйте. Самый популярный сериализатор - JSON.NET - вполне его поддерживает.

Вам нужно получить `Dictionary<string, Range>`, где `Range`:

```
// переименовать по желанию
public class Range
{
    public string Min { get; set; }

    public string Max { get; set; }
}
```

Десериализация:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Range>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Рискну предложить рукописный вариант конвертора, они не очень сложные в доработке под свои задачи, вот [пример](https://github.com/PetersSharp/stCoCServer/blob/8d24ef2e9664898522bb1d37492f89b222506fce/stCoCServer/stExtLib/stSqlite-dll/stConvert.cs#L187) такого конвертера с возможностью задавать формат исходника json с помощью [атрибутов](https://github.com/PetersSharp/stCoCServer/blob/7da9733f7106359e1dc1d223629938021835d48c/stCoCServer/stExtLib/stSqlite-dll/stConvertAttribute.cs#L19).
Буду рад если мой ответ поможет вам выбрать оптимальное решение.