# Парсинг JSON массива в c# (Ответ с примерами)

Tags: c#, json, парсер

Есть код json:

```
 {"status":"ok","meta":{"count":640},"data":{"1":{"tank_id":1},"3137":{"tank_id":3137}}
```

Как получить tank_id, если название подмассива в data всегда меняет название: "1", "3137" и т.д.?

Comment: парсите data как `Dictionary<int, ...>`

Comment: @tym32167 для подобных вопросов хорошо подходит [такая закрывашка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987)

Comment: @AK дольше искать закрывашку, чем ответ написать ). Но спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сгенерируем классы для десериализации

```
public class Meta
{
    public int count { get; set; }
}


public class Item
{
    public int tank_id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Item> data { get; set; }
}
```

Вот ваш json

```
string json = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"meta\":{\"count\":640},\"data\":{\"1\":{\"tank_id\":1},\"3137\":{\"tank_id\":3137}}}";
```

Воспользуемся библиотекой [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.data[1].tank_id);
Console.WriteLine(obj.data[3137].tank_id);
```

Готово. Вывод:

```
1
3137
```

*UPD*

Ещё пара примеров доступа к данным

```
foreach (var key in obj.data.Keys)
{
    var item = obj.data[key];
    Console.WriteLine(item.tank_id);
}

foreach (var item in obj.data.Values)
{       
    Console.WriteLine(item.tank_id);
}
```

Вывод будет тот же самый для каждого из примеров

Comment: можно ли как-то иначе обращаться, не используя число в data[1] или других объектах, потому что записей таких много, и изначально мы не знаем их номер?

Comment: @ValeryMelnikov добавил примеры

Comment: Спасибо большое!