# Как передать тип параметром функции c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, rest

Хочу написать функцию для упрощения получения GET реквестов между winforms и web_api.

Вот функция

```
public  RestResponse GetRest(string client_str,Type typ)
{
    var client = new RestClient(client_str);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("GET", "application/json");
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.Content = "application/json"; };
    return  client.Execute <typ>(request);
}
```

Но выдает ошибку, что `typ` переменная, а используется как тип.

Comment: У вас в коде переменная `typ` не используется, зачем вы ее передаете?

Comment: попробуйте `return  client.Execute <typ>(request);` возможно вы ошиблись при написании кода.

Comment: @Monomax, так не получится

Comment: @Anamnian Да, это я ошибся,когда код редактировал, просто пробовал множество способов.

Comment: @Monomax "Но выдает ошибку, что typ переменная, а используется как тип."

Comment: тогда у вас вопрос не правильно сформирован, вам нужно понять какие свойства вы получаете, и в общем-то вообще почитать про десериализацию, а в частности посмотреть [json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c/829931#829931)

Comment: возможно я ошибаюсь, и у вас передаваемый вами класс typ существует, но тогда вам нужно использовать попробуйте `return client.Execute <typeof(typ)>(request);` Но судя по тому что вы не приняли ответ №1, то у вас такого класса не существует, а значит вам надо его соответствующим образом создать.

Comment: @Monomax при использовании typeof() то же сообщение, что переменная используется как тип. 
Тип который я хочу передать в функцию может быть различным, то ли созданный класс, то ли список объектов этого класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать так

```
public RestResponse GetRest<T>(string client_str) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient(client_str);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("GET", "application/json");
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.Content = "application/json"; };
    return client.Execute<T>(request);
}
```

Пример вызова

```
var result = GetRest<MyClass>(string client_str);
```

**UPD**

Два компилирующихся варианта:

Если надо вернуть только данные

```
public T GetRest<T>(string client_str) where T:new()
{
    var client = new RestClient(client_str);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("GET", "application/json");
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
    return client.Execute<T>(request).Data;
}
```

Если надо вернуть типизированный ответ

```
public IRestResponse<T> GetRest<T>(string client_str) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient(client_str);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("GET", "application/json");
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
    return client.Execute<T>(request);
}
```

Comment: Ошибка CS0310 "T" должен быть неабстрактным типом и иметь открытый конструктор без параметров, чтобы использовать его в качестве параметра "T" в универсальном типе или методе

Comment: @VladislavDvdvch: А как вы вызываете метод?

Comment: @VladD ругается ещё до компиляции и вызова.

Comment: @VladislavDvdvch: А как у вас определён `Execute`?

Comment: @VladD как метод

Comment: @VladislavDvdvch: Давайте код :)

Comment: @VladD так это метод из библиотеки RestSharp. Весь код я уже скинул)

Comment: @VladislavDvdvch: Ну вы могли бы посмотреть в документацию или исходники RestSharp, и увидеть констрейнт `where T : new()`. Примените этот же констрейнт к функции `GetRest`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, добавил в ответ. Писал код без студии, потому проверить возможности не было

Comment: @tym32167
Ошибка CS0266 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "RestSharp.IRestResponse<T>" в "RestSharp.RestResponse". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов). 
Простите за мою некомпетентность, но сам в вопросе разобраться не могу. Мало опыта :(

Comment: @VladislavDvdvch добавил, глядите

Comment: @tym32167 огромное спасибо!)
Второе - то что мне нужно было!)