# Как извлечь из файла нужные строки?

Tags: c#

У меня есть файл в котором хранятся нужные строчки которые нужно извлечь, 
для извлечения одной части записи работает такой код:

```
string TLine = File.ReadAllLines(Text.df)[3].Split('"')[1];
```

Далее просто записываю найденные строки в файл.

И так же мне нужно прочитать остальные строчки `ReadAllLines(Text.df)[11].Split('"')[1]`

Их можно как-нибудь совместить, чтобы можно было прочитать все данные из нужной колонки `[3].Split('"')[1] и [11].Split('"')[7]`

Как можно прочитать все нужные мне данные из нужного столба?

Вот что хранится в файле:

```
"Logins"
{
  "895298918746"
  {
      "Name"        "UserName"
      "City"        "Moskow"
      "Date"        "12/10/18"
      "Num"         "14"
      "Timer"       "99999999"
  }
  "895283716281"
  {
    "Name"      "UserName"
    "City"        "Moskow"
    "Date"        "12/10/18"
    "Num"         "14"
    "Timer"       "99999999"
  }
}
```

Мне нужно получить значение 895298918746 и значение UserName из поля Name

И.т.д 895283716281  и значение UserName из поля Name

Comment: Вы бы приложили формат файла и хотя бы одну строк. Ну а вообще, обращение по индексу я лично считаю костылем...

Comment: Ну вы результат `File.ReadAllLines(Text.df)` сохраните в переменную и потом обращайтесь к нему. В чем проблема?

Comment: Ну с этого и надо было начинать. Это JSON и работать с ним явно надо не через Split.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Я же вам дал ответ. Десериализируете в Dictionary и ключом будет ваше "рандомное" значение.

Comment: Хоть это и похоже на json, но без двоеточий таковым не является.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Хм, и то верно. не заметил. И запятые упущены. Странный формат тогда...

Comment: Подскажите что можно сделать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ такой формат называется vdf и использеутся, например, в конфигах CS 1.6))

Comment: @return Не поверите, но я знаю этот формат, но это не отменяет его странность, будто Valve специально палки в колеса людям вставляют. Тут же я изначально думал, что у автора он просто битый, по этом и дубликат.

Answer (score 1):

Пятница, вечер, самое время для регулярок...

```
var data = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

var pattern = @"
^ \s*  "" (?'login'\d+) ""                \s*
^ \s*  {                                  \s*
^ \s*  ""Name""  \s* ""(?'Name'  .*? )""  \s*
^ \s*  ""City""  \s* ""(?'City'  .*? )""  \s*
^ \s*  ""Date""  \s* ""(?'Date'  .*? )""  \s*
^ \s*  ""Num""   \s* ""(?'Num'   .*? )""  \s*
^ \s*  ""Timer"" \s* ""(?'Timer' .*? )""  \s*
^ \s*  }
";

var options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline;
var matches = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, options);

var users = new List<User>();

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Login = m.Groups["login"].Value,
        Name = m.Groups["Name"].Value,
        City = m.Groups["City"].Value,
        Date = m.Groups["Date"].Value,
        Num = int.Parse(m.Groups["Num"].Value),
        Timer = int.Parse(m.Groups["Timer"].Value)
    };
    users.Add(user);
}
```

Класс-модель для хранения информации о пользователе:

```
public class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public int Timer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: А по мимо регулярных выражений как ещё можно?

Comment: @Дмитрий - Используя методы класс [String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2): `Substring`, `Contains`, `StartsWith`, `Split` и другие.

Comment: Ну это понятно) Были бы примеры ещё подобные. Так-то я не особо шарю как совместить всё это