# Разбить строку на две части в C#

Tags: c#

Как разбить строку на C# на две части по запятой во второй строке?

```
{"inn":"123456789012","ogrn":"111111111111111","IP":{"fio":"Иванов Иван Иванович","okpo":"2222222222","okato":"22222222222","status":{"statusString":"plus"}},"contactPhones":{}} 
,
{"inn":"123456789012","ogrn":"111111111122222","IP":{"fio":"Иванов Иван Иванович","okopf":"12345","registrationDate":"2007-01-12","status":{"statusString":"тест","dissolved":true,"date":"2009-04-16"}}, "Report":{"summary":{"test":true}},"contactPhones":{}}
```

Так `str.Split(new char[] { ',' });`  не подходит, на каждой запятой разбивается.

---

Взяла вот такую строку:

```
{"ogrn":"123456789078901","inn":"1111111111111"},{"ogrn":"111111111111111","inn":"2222222222222"}
```

Создала класс:

```
public class testObject
{
    public string inn { get; set; } //
    public string ogrn { get; set; } //
}

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, testObject>>(json);
```

Выходит ошибка: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "123456789078901" to type 'Sved.Form1+testObject'. Path 'ogrn', line 1, position 25. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Sved.Form1+testObject.

Не понимаю, что не так.

Comment: Если это валидный JSON, то работайте с ним как с JSON, не надо разбирать его ручками

Comment: попробуйте использовать сериализацию по [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c/829931#829931](JSON), и проблем не будет.

Comment: @Monomax, спасибо!

Comment: Я взяла строку попроще, чтобы попробовать разобрать её, выходит ошибка.

Comment: ошибка потомучто у вас строка не массив а как обект массив должен начинатся с [ а у вас с { просто  добавте в начле и конце по [ и ] соответсвено высериализуете как коллекцию

Comment: а зачем вообще в словать сериализовать сделайте модель и все

Comment: думаю ошибка из за сериализации в словарь

Comment: У вас не верный JSON. Вы имеете две строки `{"ogrn":"123456789078901","inn":"1111111111111"}`, которые не как не связаны и каждая будет заменять друг друга. Правильный JSON будет тогда, когда ваша строка будет в массиве обозначенным `[ *** ]` кавычками. Тогда ваш тип будет `List<testObject>` (или `testObject[]`). Сейчас это просто `testObject`, без словаря.

Comment: всем спасибо! кроме [ ] , мне было непонятно, какой тип использовать. Работает: List <testObject> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<testObject>>(json)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Answer (score 1):

Если несколько объектов - надо делать JSON такого типа:

```
[{"ogrn":"123456789078901","inn":"1111111111111"},{"ogrn":"111111111111111","inn":"2222222222222"}]
```

Вы забыли эти объекты поместить в массив объектов. Так же чтобы не было таких названий переменных в коде, можно добавлять атрибуты:

```
private class SomeObject
{
    [JsonProperty("ogrn")] public string first;

    [JsonProperty("inn")] public string second;
}
```

JsonProperty из Newtonsoft.Json;