# C# -- Newtonsoft.Json JProperty.Value<T>() не может вернуть значение указанного типа

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Есть JSON:

```
{
  "Table1": {
    "Field1": "abc",
    "Field2": "def"
  }
}
```

И есть код:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(myJson);
foreach (JProperty table in data.Properties())
{
    tables.Add(table.Name, new TableFields(table.Value<JObject>())); // <- тут ошибка
}
```

При выполнении кода выдает исключение `InvalidCastException` и говорит, что невозможно преобразовать значение в `JObject`. Почему так?

---

Пока что я прописал костыль `JObject.Parse(table.Value.ToString())`. Но далее я пытаюсь у полей со строками получить значения в формате `String` и опять получаю эту ошибку. Вот код:

```
public TableFields(JObject source)
{
    data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (JProperty prop in source.Properties()) data.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value<String>());
}
```

Что это за бред такой? Тем более у этих `JProperty` в поле `Type` везде указаны именно те типы, к которым я пытаюсь привести: `JObject` в первом случае и `String` во втором.

Comment: Вы бы привели соурс чего там парсите в читаемом виде, так догадаться невозможно. А `tables` класс что из себя представляет?

Comment: В самом начале приведен JSON.

Comment: замени на `(JObject)table.Value`

Comment: @Grundy А во втором случае что делать?

Comment: ничего, он работает

Comment: Ваш json имеет простую классическую структуру, поэтому десериализацию можно провести штатными средствами `JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyType>(data)`. Вместо этого вы пошли читать и разбирать структуру на более низком уровне, что делается крайне редко и только для кастомных json-объектов. Скажите, у вас чем-то мотивирована такая потребность или вас устроит типовое решение по десериализации json.net?

Comment: @AK, набор полей-то меняется

Comment: @Grundy Во-первых, из приведённого json этого не видно. Во-вторых, есть классическая [закрывашка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987) на ассоциированные массивы. Вон, даже сам автор создал `Dictionary<string, string>()`

Comment: @AK Я не думал о таком подходе. Возможно, что такое решение мне подойдет. Сейчас пойду пробовать.

Comment: @AK, любой json можно как dictionary, Но потом с ним не всегда удобно работать

Comment: Удобно только если весь JSON состоит только из строк. Но сейчас это как раз такая ситуация. @AK вы можете оформить это в виде ответа. Я его отмечу.

Comment: @Eevee Можно гораздо проще - закрыть как дубликат вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используемый вами метод `Extensions.Value<T>(this IEnumerable<JToken> value)` пытается преобразовать в указанный вами тип не значение свойства `JProperty`, а само свойство (пару из ключа и значения). Такая операция не имеет смысла, отсюда и ошибка.

Вместо этого следует использовать свойство `JProperty.Value`, чтобы получить именно значение свойства:

```
(JObject)table.Value
(string)prop.Value
```

Также можно использовать сначала свойство `Value`, а потом - метод:

```
table.Value.Value<JObject>()
prop.Value.Value<string>()
```

Comment: Точно. Это именно то, что я хотел узнать. Я попробовал и так все действительно заработало.