# Десериализация пустого словаря в Json.Net без JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

Tags: php, c#, json, json.net

Существует сервис на PHP, от которого я получаю json и выполняю при помощи Json.Net парсинг.

Вот так выглядит упрощённо мой запрос:

```
var result = this.GetTestData1();

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);

private string GetTestData1()
{
    return @"
        {
          'students': {
           '123': 100,
           '1234': 404,
          }
        }
    ";
}
```

Где классы [для десериализации словаря](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987) выглядят так:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("students")]
    public Dictionary<string, StudentResult> StudentsResults { get; set; }
}

public enum StudentResult
{
    Success = 100,
    ContactPersonNotFound = 404,
}
```

Но есть вот какая проблема. В случае если PHP отправит пустой массив, то я падаю с ошибкой JsonSerializationException:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,UserQuery+StudentResult]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path 'students', line 3, position 17.

Проблема в том, что PHP неожиданно отправляет этот json со скобками не фигурными (`{}`), а квадратными (`[]`):

```
private string GetTestData2()
{
    return @"
        {
          'students': []
        }
    ";
}
```

Точнее, проблема в том, что <s>мопед не мой</s> я не могу заставить на стороне PHP включить JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (см. [например тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28189390/5752652))

Поэтому ищутся варианты решения, пусть даже и в виде костылей, на стороне Json.Net, а не на стороне PHP.

Сам искал по документации штуки типа NullValueHandling/DefaultValueHandling/ObjectCreationHandling - но похоже, что всё не то. :(

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ тут: [How to deserialize object that can be an array or a dictionary with Newtonsoft?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505097/5752652)

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("students")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EmptyArrayOrDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, StudentResult> StudentsResults { get; set; }
}

public class EmptyArrayOrDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            return token.ToObject(objectType);
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            if (!token.HasValues)
            {
                // create empty dictionary
                return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
            }
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException("Object or empty array expected");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Не хватает обработки existingValue - например, на тот случай когда мутатора у свойства нет.

Comment: 2. Лучше всё-таки работать с JsonReader потоковым способом, а не грузить всё в JToken - меньше памяти потребуется.

Comment: 3. Ваш CanConvert возвращает false для вашего типа. Вам повезло что Json.Net его не вызывает...