# Регулярное выражение для поиска числа в строке

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь постигнуть регулярки - нужна помощь. Есть такая строка:

```
{"Cur_ID":145,"Date":"2020-01-29T00:00:00","Cur_Abbreviation":"USD","Cur_Scale":1,"Cur_Name":"Доллар США","Cur_OfficialRate":2.1283}
```

Из неё нужно вытянуть число: `2.1283` или любое другое число c плавающей точкой в этой позиции.

Подскажите с объяснением, как это сделать.

Comment: Это не строка, а словарь. Нужно просто обратиться к нужному элементу.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, если бы я парсил это в соответствующий класс. Но это строка, и из неё с помощью регулярки нужно вытянуть указанное число.

Comment: Вы знаете что такое JSON? Зачем вам тут регулярка? Берите, десериализуйте его нужным инструментом и забирайте нужное значение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю за совет, но конкретно в этом случае есть задача: с помощью регулярного выражения достать это число. Я имею представление о JSON, знаю как можно было бы его десериализовать, но этого делать не буду.

Comment: Ну так напишите это в вопросе, почему нельзя и тд, ибо сейчас такое впечатление, что вы банальный новичок, который не знает даже основ языка, который хочет работать с курсом валют... Костыли писать мало кто просто так хочет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ по-моему, в вопросе предельно понятно из контекста, что есть определённая строка, есть определённое число, которое нужно из него достать с помощью регулярного выражения. Если я там буду перечислять все методы, которыми нельзя пользоваться(вкл. десериализацию), то конкретики вопросу это не прибавит, а лишь будет отвлекать.

Comment: Вытягивай: ````2\.1283````

Comment: @Qwertiy а это случаем не для конкретного числа? Просто поставь туда другое число - все рухнет. UPD: исправил формулировку вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из имеющейся строки можно достать такой регуляркой (надо брать первую группу):

```
"Cur_OfficialRate":\s*(\d*\.?\d*)
```

Но вообще, строка явно является json'ом, поэтому можно её распарсить как json в словарь и просто достать значение по соответствующему ключу.