# Пытаюсь распарсить json, но как-то не получается

Tags: c#, json, парсер, json.net

Я пробовал

```
dynamic stuff = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"https://www.instagram.com/p/BGwG0OKlxr9/?__a=1");тут ссылка была, и распарсенный string
string color = stuff.name;
Console.WriteLine(color);
```

```
var updates = (JContainer)JObject.Parse(тут ссылка была, и распарсенный string);
dynamic results = updates.Descendants().OfType<JObject>().Where(x => x["full_name"] != null).FirstOrDefault();
```

распарсенный стринг я получаю так

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.instagram.com/p/BGwG0OKlxr9/?__a=1");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-urlencoded";

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream()) 
{
   using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(s)) 
   {
       str = r.ReadToEnd(); 
   }
}
response.Close();
Console.Read();
```

Но как только я не пытался подставлять и тп, ничего не работает, точнее ничего не выводит в консоль, только выводит распарсенный string с json и тп в консоль, есть предположения в чем проблемма?

Comment: Используйте `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourTypeWithJsonSchema>(inputString)` Где для создания класса YourTypeWithJsonSchema смотрите например этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как говориться, "делаем на коленке".

Пишем такой код в консольной проге

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var requestUri = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BGwG0OKlxr9/?__a=1";

        string json = String.Empty;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.GetAsync(requestUri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Ставим точку останова и запускаем, смотрим значение `json`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нажимаем на лупу и видим содержимое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выделяем все содержимое и копируем. Далее идем http://json2csharp.com, вставляем и получаем набор нужных классов. Копируем их и создаем у себя в проекте.

Далее дописываем строку парсинга, запускаем и смотрим на результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за step by spet подробный)

Comment: Да, пожалуйста 