# Помощь в парсинге json на C#

Tags: c#, json, парсер

Имею такой json

```
`{
    "Date": "2020-04-09T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousDate": "2020-04-08T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousURL": "\/\/www.cbr-xml-daily.ru\/archive\/2020\/04\/08\/daily_json.js",
    "Timestamp": "2020-04-08T23:00:00+03:00",
    "Valute": {
        "AUD": {
            "ID": "R01010",
            "NumCode": "036",
            "CharCode": "AUD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Австралийский доллар",
            "Value": 46.4801,
            "Previous": 46.6312
        },
        "AZN": {
            "ID": "R01020A",
            "NumCode": "944",
            "CharCode": "AZN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Азербайджанский манат",
            "Value": 44.6507,
            "Previous": 44.4769
        },
        "GBP": {
            "ID": "R01035",
            "NumCode": "826",
            "CharCode": "GBP",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства",
            "Value": 93.233,
            "Previous": 93.0662
        },
        "AMD": {
            "ID": "R01060",
            "NumCode": "051",
            "CharCode": "AMD",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Армянских драмов",
            "Value": 15.1697,
            "Previous": 15.0534
        },
        "BYN": {
            "ID": "R01090B",
            "NumCode": "933",
            "CharCode": "BYN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Белорусский рубль",
            "Value": 29.6989,
            "Previous": 29.5612
        },
        "BGN": {
            "ID": "R01100",
            "NumCode": "975",
            "CharCode": "BGN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Болгарский лев",
            "Value": 42.0436,
            "Previous": 41.9311
        },
        "BRL": {
            "ID": "R01115",
            "NumCode": "986",
            "CharCode": "BRL",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Бразильский реал",
            "Value": 14.5031,
            "Previous": 14.274
        },
        "HUF": {
            "ID": "R01135",
            "NumCode": "348",
            "CharCode": "HUF",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Венгерских форинтов",
            "Value": 22.9201,
            "Previous": 22.7589
        },
        "HKD": {
            "ID": "R01200",
            "NumCode": "344",
            "CharCode": "HKD",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Гонконгских долларов",
            "Value": 97.7153,
            "Previous": 97.3224
        },
        "DKK": {
            "ID": "R01215",
            "NumCode": "208",
            "CharCode": "DKK",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Датская крона",
            "Value": 11.0167,
            "Previous": 10.9849
        },
        "USD": {
            "ID": "R01235",
            "NumCode": "840",
            "CharCode": "USD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Доллар США",
            "Value": 75.7499,
            "Previous": 75.455
        },
        "EUR": {
            "ID": "R01239",
            "NumCode": "978",
            "CharCode": "EUR",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Евро",
            "Value": 82.2341,
            "Previous": 82.012
        },
        "INR": {
            "ID": "R01270",
            "NumCode": "356",
            "CharCode": "INR",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Индийских рупий",
            "Value": 99.175,
            "Previous": 99.7673
        },
        "KZT": {
            "ID": "R01335",
            "NumCode": "398",
            "CharCode": "KZT",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Казахстанских тенге",
            "Value": 17.3788,
            "Previous": 17.2656
        },
        "CAD": {
            "ID": "R01350",
            "NumCode": "124",
            "CharCode": "CAD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Канадский доллар",
            "Value": 53.9068,
            "Previous": 53.8004
        },
        "KGS": {
            "ID": "R01370",
            "NumCode": "417",
            "CharCode": "KGS",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Киргизских сомов",
            "Value": 89.2242,
            "Previous": 88.877
        },
        "CNY": {
            "ID": "R01375",
            "NumCode": "156",
            "CharCode": "CNY",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Китайский юань",
            "Value": 10.7178,
            "Previous": 10.696
        },
        "MDL": {
            "ID": "R01500",
            "NumCode": "498",
            "CharCode": "MDL",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Молдавских леев",
            "Value": 41.1684,
            "Previous": 40.6218
        },
        "NOK": {
            "ID": "R01535",
            "NumCode": "578",
            "CharCode": "NOK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Норвежских крон",
            "Value": 73.3847,
            "Previous": 73.5924
        },
        "PLN": {
            "ID": "R01565",
            "NumCode": "985",
            "CharCode": "PLN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Польский злотый",
            "Value": 18.1194,
            "Previous": 18.0757
        },
        "RON": {
            "ID": "R01585F",
            "NumCode": "946",
            "CharCode": "RON",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Румынский лей",
            "Value": 17.011,
            "Previous": 16.9787
        },
        "XDR": {
            "ID": "R01589",
            "NumCode": "960",
            "CharCode": "XDR",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "СДР (специальные права заимствования)",
            "Value": 103.1638,
            "Previous": 102.4845
        },
        "SGD": {
            "ID": "R01625",
            "NumCode": "702",
            "CharCode": "SGD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Сингапурский доллар",
            "Value": 53.0276,
            "Previous": 52.9212
        },
        "TJS": {
            "ID": "R01670",
            "NumCode": "972",
            "CharCode": "TJS",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Таджикских сомони",
            "Value": 74.0468,
            "Previous": 73.903
        },
        "TRY": {
            "ID": "R01700J",
            "NumCode": "949",
            "CharCode": "TRY",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Турецкая лира",
            "Value": 11.1564,
            "Previous": 11.2234
        },
        "TMT": {
            "ID": "R01710A",
            "NumCode": "934",
            "CharCode": "TMT",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Новый туркменский манат",
            "Value": 21.6738,
            "Previous": 21.5894
        },
        "UZS": {
            "ID": "R01717",
            "NumCode": "860",
            "CharCode": "UZS",
            "Nominal": 10000,
            "Name": "Узбекских сумов",
            "Value": 78.0846,
            "Previous": 78.0865
        },
        "UAH": {
            "ID": "R01720",
            "NumCode": "980",
            "CharCode": "UAH",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Украинских гривен",
            "Value": 27.7828,
            "Previous": 27.8478
        },
        "CZK": {
            "ID": "R01760",
            "NumCode": "203",
            "CharCode": "CZK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Чешских крон",
            "Value": 30.1889,
            "Previous": 30.039
        },
        "SEK": {
            "ID": "R01770",
            "NumCode": "752",
            "CharCode": "SEK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Шведских крон",
            "Value": 75.1994,
            "Previous": 75.4437
        },
        "CHF": {
            "ID": "R01775",
            "NumCode": "756",
            "CharCode": "CHF",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Швейцарский франк",
            "Value": 77.916,
            "Previous": 77.5408
        },
        "ZAR": {
            "ID": "R01810",
            "NumCode": "710",
            "CharCode": "ZAR",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Южноафриканских рэндов",
            "Value": 41.1993,
            "Previous": 41.194
        },
        "KRW": {
            "ID": "R01815",
            "NumCode": "410",
            "CharCode": "KRW",
            "Nominal": 1000,
            "Name": "Вон Республики Корея",
            "Value": 62.0179,
            "Previous": 62.1042
        },
        "JPY": {
            "ID": "R01820",
            "NumCode": "392",
            "CharCode": "JPY",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Японских иен",
            "Value": 69.6391,
            "Previous": 69.3106
        }
    }
}`
```

Мне нужно достать свойства CharCode, Name и Value для каждой валюты. Проблема в том, что класс делать у меня не получается, т.к. как я понимаю, в этом файле для каждой валюты свой класс.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("data.json", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
        var objJson = JObject.Parse(json);

        var currencies = objJson["Valute"].Children()
                                   .SelectMany(v => v.Children())
                                   .Select(c => new
                                   {
                                       CharCode = (string)c["CharCode"],
                                       Name = (string)c["Name"],
                                       Value = (decimal)c["Value"],
                                   });

        foreach (var currency in currencies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name:{currency.Name}, " +
                $"CharCode:{currency.CharCode}, Value:{currency.Value}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```