# Возможно ли сделать динамичное json значение

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Я получаю json, в котором значение все время меняется, это значение я не могу обойти.

Json:

```
{
  "country": {
    "20613": {
      "cases": [
        {
          "caseType": 1,
          "name": "ОАЭ"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 2,
          "name": "ОАЭ"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 3,
          "name": "ОАЭ"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 4,
          "name": "ОАЭ"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 5,
          "name": "ОАЭ"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 6,
          "name": "ОАЭ"
        }
      ],
      "preposition": "в"
    }
  },
  "region": {},
  "city": {
    "274286": {
      "cases": [
        {
          "caseType": 1,
          "name": "Москва"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 2,
          "name": "Москвы"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 3,
          "name": "Москве"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 4,
          "name": "Москву"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 5,
          "name": "Москвой"
        },
        {
          "caseType": 6,
          "name": "Москве"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

20613 будет менятся, как мне объявить так, чтобы он брал значение из основного класса.

Пример:

```
public partial class Cou
{
    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public Countryse Countryse { get; set; }
}

public partial class Countryse
{
    [JsonProperty("caseType")]
    public long CaseType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Я не могу никак константу сделать в `NameCountry()` классе.

Как я могу это обойти?

```
var countryjs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Countryse>>(bca);
var data = countryjs[NameCountry()].Name;
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Ошибка:

```
The given key '20613' was not present in the dictionary.
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Это не дубликат, там я вообще не нашел подобного, там нету динамичного json. У меня класс создается с определенным названием, а это название будет менятся все время. Я нашел выход в том, что я могу отловить это значение, но класс json не хочет его принимать, т.к не константа. Мне нужно каждый раз давать какое будет название для  `public The20613 The20613 { get; set; }`

Comment: Так у вас не класс с названием должен быть, а словарь, где ключом является это самое название, в вашем случае `20613` - это ключ.

Comment: @ Я понял как делать дальше, но не могу класс составить, можете помочь, вопрос отредактировал

Comment: Я не вижу ваш JSON, как я могу вам помочь?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ забыл добавить

Comment: Ну давайте посмотрим на вашу JSON [структуру](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjPDi.png), что мы видим тут? А то, что в главном узле у нас 3 объекта (country, region, city), то есть у вас должен быть класс, например Root, который внутри содержит 3 свойства `public Dictionary<int, Case> Country {get;set;}` (и по аналогии) и в этот класс уже должна идти десериализация, а вы пытаетесь засунуть сразу в `Dictionary<string, Countryse>. Дальше уже `Case` содержит в себе массив неких объектов, под названием `Cases` и некое свойство `Preposition`. В итоге получаем [такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WlI1H4).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за подробное объяснение