# Как сохранить простой словарь в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Как сохранить простой словарь Dictionary <int, string> в Unity?

Видел несколько мудренных способов, но с такими же "мудренными" словарями.
Скорее всего, JSON, самый лучший вариант. Но так же я понимаю, что словарь не сериализуется.

Я новичок, помогите пожалуйста :)

Comment: Сохранить куда? В файл? В базу?

Comment: Ну в JSON файл. (Если же Player Prefs лучше справится с этой задачей, тогда в реестр).  Еще раз извините, я далеко не компетентный в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Json.Net и примерно такой сниппет:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    {1, "Foo"},
    {2, "Bar"},
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict);

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\123.json", json);
```

Содержимое файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратная операция описана в классической закрывашке: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987)

Comment: @A_K а почему нельзя сделать также с помощью JsonUtility.ToJson? Какая разница между этим и JsonConvert? Или можно сериализовать  словарь с помощью JsonUtility? Я просто читал, что словари несериализуемы и их нужны разбивать на структуры ключи и значения?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Почитал что такое JsonUtility.ToJson - похоже, что это штатная в unity3d штука. Не знал, отвечал исходя из общешарповых представлений и знаний. Не знаю, какая разница в выходном json будет, теоретически не должно быть, но [возможны нюансы](https://habr.com/en/company/mailru/blog/314014/). Насчёт возможностей JsonUtility не подскажу, я больше работал с json.net - там словари спокойно сериализуются и десериализуются. В принципе, если хочется unity3d-way - то второй шаг можете заменить на JsonUtility.ToJson

Comment: @AK В том то и дело, что JsonUtility не сериализует словари. То есть их не будет вообще в конечном JSON файле (ну или будут пустые фигурные скобки). Это надо леать, разбивая словарь на структуры ключей и значений. Ну ладно. А можно же с помощью вашего JsonConvert засериализовать не словарь, а целый класс? Это будет делаться также: `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
`?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Да, класс можно, это самый частый сценарий в Json.net.