# Помогите привести код к подобному виду

Tags: c#, классы

Нужно создать класс, чтобы после сериализации он выглядел как в первом блоке кода. Как работать с json и xml я понимаю, вопрос в создании класса. Русский язык используется только для примера.

Требуется чтобы был один класс, в идеале. Для того чтобы его как один объект сериализовать.

```json
{
  "Пользователь":{
    "Факультет": "Тестовый факультет",
    "Корпус": "Корпус тестового факультета",
    "Кабинет": "100",
    "Название кабинета": "Деканат тестового факультета",
    "Инвентарный номер": 00006969,
    "Используется для":[
      "Управление, организ. Уч. проц-в"
    ],
    "Подключен к интернету": "Да",
    "Подключен к мультимедиа": "Да",
    "Количество пользователей": 1,
    "ФИО пользователей":[
      "Павлов А.И."
    ],
    "Примечание": "Все работает"
  },
  "Компьютер":{
    "Имя компьютера": "COMPUTER",
    "Имя пользователя": "User",
    "Процессор": "Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E666 @ 3.33GHz",
    "Оперативная память": 4096,
    "Объем жестких дисков": 1006,
    "Видеокарта": "NVIDIA GeForce 710",
    "Операционная система": "Windows 8.1",
    "Устройства вывода изображения": "Универсальный монитор PnP",
    "Физические адреса": [
      "IPv4":[
        "192.168.73.1",
        "192.168.96.1"
      ],
      "IPv6":[
        "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0", 
        "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0"
      ],
      "MAC":[
        "0A:00:27:00:00:4C",
        "0A:00:27:00:00:4A"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Как я примерно это вижу

```cs
SystemInfoContainer sic = new SystemInfoContainer();

sic.User.Faculty = "Тестовый факультет";

sic.Hardware.Username = "Username";

XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SystemInfoContainer));

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("SystemInfo.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                xml.Serialize(fs, sic);
            }
```

Comment: Ты на выходе хочешь такой json получить? Или это вход?

Comment: Это то что должно выйти после сериализации

Comment: Взять Json.Net написать класс и расставить атрибуты с русскими именами.

Comment: Я и прошу помочь мне написать класс. Как работать с json я понимаю.

Comment: Вот вам лучшая помощь: есть множество готовых сервисов, которые вам напишут по образцу json класс, посмотрите например этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987

Comment: Вы допустили несколько ошибок при формировании данных 1) "Количество пользователей" - можно выкинуть, так как дальше идет их список и по количеству записей в нем можно определить количество. Данные дублировать нельзя. 2) "Физические адреса" - массив с массивами, среди которых физические адреса - только MAC. В общем, здесь синтаксическая ошибка, должен быть объект, а у вас массив. Должно быть `"Физические адреса": {`, то есть фигурная скобка, а не квадратная. 3) "Подключен к интернету": "Да" - почему не `True`/`False`?

Comment: На счет "количества пользователей" согласен, русский язык только для примера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитав несколько статей, просмотрев несколько видео вроде как теперь имею понятие как это сделать.

Спустя несколько часов, нашел вот этот прекрасный сайт https://json2csharp.com/.

Вот мой класс:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JSONTest

{

    public class SystemInfoContainer
    {

        public User UserInfo { get; set; }

        public Computer HardwareInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Faculty { get; set; }
        public string Corpus { get; set; }
        public string Cabinet { get; set; }
        public string CabinetName { get; set; }
        public string InventoryNumber { get; set; }
        public List<string> UsedFor { get; set; }
        public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
        public bool IsMultimedia { get; set; }
        public bool IsScienceDevices { get; set; }
        public List<string> UsersFullNames { get; set; }
        public string Additions { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhysAddr
    {
        public IList<string> IPv4Addresses { get; set; }
        public IList<string> IPv6Addresses { get; set; }
        public IList<string> MACAddresses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Computer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Userame { get; set; }
        public string Processor { get; set; }
        public int RAM { get; set; }
        public int HDD { get; set; }
        public string Videocard { get; set; }
        public string OS { get; set; }
        public string Output { get; set; }
        public IList<PhysAddr> PhysicalAddresses { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Вот мой код для создания объекта:

```cs
SystemInfoContainer sysinf = new SystemInfoContainer();

sysinf.UserInfo = new User()
{
  Faculty = "Тестовый факультет",
  Corpus = "Корпус тестового факультета",
  Cabinet = "100",
  CabinetName = "Деканат тестового факультета",
  InventoryNumber = "00006969",
  UsedFor = new List<string> { "Управление, организ. Уч. проц-в" },
  IsConnected = true,
  IsMultimedia = true,
  IsScienceDevices = false,
  UsersFullNames = new List<string> { "Павлов А.И." },
  Additions = "Все работает"
};

sysinf.HardwareInfo = new Computer()
{
  Name = "COMPUTER",
  Userame = "User",
  Processor = "Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E666 @ 3.33GHz",
  RAM = 4096,
  HDD = 1006,
  Videocard = "NVIDIA GeForce 710",
  OS = "Windows 8.1",
  Output = "Универсальный монитор PnP",
  PhysicalAddresses = new List<PhysAddr>()
  {
    new PhysAddr() {
      IPv4Addresses  = new List<string>()
      {
        "192.168.73.1",
        "192.168.96.1"
        },
        IPv6Addresses  = new List<string>()
        {
          "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0",
          "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0"
          },
          MACAddresses  = new List<string>()
          {
            "0A:00:27:00:00:4C",
            "0A:00:27:00:00:4A"
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Всем спасибо за советы и за первый ответ который помог мне понять как они работают.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Unicode;

namespace JsonSerializeExample
{
    public class Workplace
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Пользователь")]
        public User User { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Компьютер")]
        public Computer Computer { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Используется для")]
        public List<string> UsedFor { get; set; }
    }

    public class Computer
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Имя компьютера")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workplace = new Workplace
            {
                User = new User
                {
                    UsedFor = new List<string> { "Управление, организ. Уч. проц-в" },
                },
                Computer = new Computer
                {
                    Name = "COMPUTER",
                },
            };

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            { 
                WriteIndented = true, 
                Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, UnicodeRanges.Cyrillic),
            };

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(workplace, options);

            File.WriteAllText("workplace.json", json);        
        }
    }
}
```

```json
{
  "Пользователь": {
    "Используется для": [
      "Управление, организ. Уч. проц-в"
    ]
  },
  "Компьютер": {
    "Имя компьютера": "COMPUTER"
  }
}
```

Остальное по образу и подобию :)
P.S. Кириллица в именах свойств - зашквар, но надо - так надо :)

Comment: Это для примера