# Задать формат сериализации JSON. System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

Имею некоторую модель.

```cs
class Model
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string IconPath{get;set;}

}
```

Я не знаю, и не могу найти в интернете, с помощью каких атрибутов можно изменить форматирование при сериализации, чтобы вместо такого формата

```json
[{
  ID: "0000-0000000000-0000-0000",
  Name: "SampleName",
  IconPath: "/screns/0.jpg"},
 {
  ID: "0000-0000000000-0000-0001",
  Name: "SampleName1",
  IconPath: "/screens/1.jpg"}]
```

был такой

```json
{
  "0000-0000000000-0000-0000":{
  Name: "SampleName",
  Version: "1.10.12.0"
},
  "0000-0000000000-0000-0001":{
  Name: "SampleName1",
  Version: "1.10.12.1"
}
```

Честно говоря, проблема в том, что я наверное мог бы это и загуглить, если бы знал как правильно это называется, но не знаю. Буду рад если вы скажете как можно это реализовать, или хотя подскажите название.

Comment: Это ассоциативный массив, ключ-значение, Dictionary и т.п. На ru so есть эталонный вопрос, только в обратную сторону: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987 Сделайте себе `Dictionary<Guid, Model>` и будет вам то, что нужно.

Comment: @AK, Большое спасибо