# Парсинг JSON в List<Dictionary<string, string>> C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Подскажите в чем моя ошибка, я пишу программу, которая конвертирует `CSV` > `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` > `JSON`, а вот обратно из `JSON` > `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` я не могу.
Выдает ошибку `Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content`

Вот так я записываю из `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` в `JSON`

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> dictionary in content)
{
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
    data.SaveFile(jsonString, "json");
}
```

А обратно пытаюсь

```
using (StreamReader stream = new(Data.PathToFile))
{
    string json = stream.ReadToEnd();
    Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
    _listRecords.Add(values);
}
```

Бьет ошибку, когда пытаюсь обратно десериализовать.
Формат JSON такой (1000 записей):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что это `data.SaveFile(jsonString, "json");`? Зачем словари по одному сериализовать? Почему нельзя список словарей сериализовать?

Comment: @tym32167 а, т.е я могу передать целый список в `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`?
`data.SaveFile(jsonString, "json");` это просто стрим который записывает переданную строку файл в формате `json`

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Я сериализовал каждый элемент из списка словаря по отдельности и сохранял, а надо было весь сразу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/373567 Почитайте. Если используете .NET Core 3.1 или новее, то лушче наверное использовать `System.Text.Json` - [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).