# Split string[] array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq

Всем привет
Можете подсказать, у меня на вход будет приходить какой-то массив данных.
Примерно так будет выглядеть(JSON):
{
"Address":"New York", "Phone": "007008009"
}
Как мне из этого массива выхватить только "New York" и "007008009"?
Как-то попробовать через .Split?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Это будет не Json file, это будет какой-то объект. Я просто показал на примере Json, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: То есть надо распарсить то, непонятно что?

Comment: Почему непонятно что? Массив стрингов

Comment: Содержащих что? Вы или показывайте то что надо распарсить, или прекращаем в гадалки играть. Показали JSON - выше вам подробный ответ как распарсить JSON. Если надо что-то другое, то я не телепат.

Comment: JSON нужно парсить с помощью json-парсера. XML нужно парсить с помощью XML-парсера. Вы пишете: "массив стрингов". Во-первых, стринги - это трусики такие. Во-вторых, формат данных должен быть известен, иначе неясно, что парсить.