# Десериализация запроса с динамическими наименованиями полей

Tags: c#

Есть запрос

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "responseId": "1234566789",
    "responseCode": "100",
    "responseCodeDescription": "Success"
  },
  "testInfo": {
    "FTest": {
      "155": {
         "test1": 1,
        "test2": 0,
        "test3": "test3",
        "test4": 0,
        "test5": 0
      },
      "101": {
         "test1": 2,
        "test2": 0,
        "test3": "test3",
        "test4": 0,
        "test5": 0
      }
    },
    "PTest": {
      "155": {
         "test1": 1,
        "test2": 0,
        "test3": "test3",
        "test4": 0,
        "test5": 0
      },
      "101": {
        "test1": 2,
        "test2": 0,
        "test3": "test3",
        "test4": 0,
        "test5": 0
      },
      "158": {
         "test1": 3,
        "test2": 0,
        "test3": "test3",
        "test4": 0,
        "test5": 0
      }
    },
    "test": "123456789",
    "total_test": 1
  }
}
```

Как его можно десериализовать в модель при условии что `"155", "101 и т.д"` могут меняться (Тоесть они постоянно меняються).

Comment: это `Dictionary<string, MyType>`, ничего необычного

Comment: Десериализация описана здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987 а сериализация ещё проще.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо!

Comment: @AK  Спасибо! Попробую!