# Как в классе Json прописать массив неопределенных элементов

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть json, в нем до определенного момента, элементы идут одинакового типа, но в `RenderCompProps`,  идут элементы с разными названиями. Я знаю что мой элемент под номером 2(`CompKk5Jd9U5`), как мне составить класс, чтобы я мог получить 2 элемент, не ставя название, т.к оно постоянно меняется.

```
public partial class Render
        {
            [JsonProperty("compProps")]
            public RenderCompProps CompProps { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class RenderCompProps
        {
            [JsonProperty("comp-kk5jd9tm")]
            public CompKk5Jd9Tm CompKk5Jd9Tm { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("comp-kk5kz06g")]
            public CompKk5Kz06G CompKk5Kz06G { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("comp-kk5jd9u5")]
            public CompKk5Jd9U5 CompKk5Jd9U5 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("pageBackground_kfrfp")]
            public PageBackgroundKfrfp PageBackgroundKfrfp { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Containerkfrfp")]
            public Containerkfrfp Containerkfrfp { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class CompKk5Jd9U5
        {
            [JsonProperty("images")]
            public Image[] Images { get; set; }
        }
```

Мне нужно получить его `CompKk5Jd9U5`.

JSON:

```
{
  "props": {
    "render": {
      "compProps": {
        "comp-kk5jd9tm": {
          "svgContent": "<svg preserveAspectRatio=\"xMidYMid meet\" data-bbox=\"13.599 30.299 173.4 144.709\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"13.599 30.299 173.4 144.709\" role=presentation aria-hidden=true>\n    <g>\n        <path d=\"M180.729 74.991c-3.863-8.609-9.438-16.376-16.394-23.085-14.443-13.934-33.462-21.607-53.471-21.607-41.808 0-75.844 33.885-75.844 75.748 0 .042-.02-.047-.019-.047H13.599l36.08 62.492L85.759 106H64.282s.003.089.003.047c0-25.714 20.698-46.547 46.357-46.547 25.224 0 46.357 20.01 46.357 43.592v57.272c0 8.087 6.912 14.644 15 14.644 8.087 0 15-6.557 15-14.644v-57.272c.001-9.64-2.228-19.094-6.27-28.101z\"/>\n    </g>\n</svg>\n",
          "shouldScaleStroke": false,
          "withShadow": false,
          "withStroke": false,
          "link": {
            "href": "https://www.bacimilano.com/collezione",
            "target": "_self",
            "anchorDataId": "dataItem-kk84guh2",
            "type": "AnchorLink"
          }
        },
        "comp-kk5kz06g": {
          "html": "<h2 class=\"font_2\" style=\"font-size:27px; text-align:center\"><span style=\"font-size:27px\"><span style=\"font-family:brandon-grot-w01-light,sans-serif\">REGINA DI CUORI</span></span></h2>\n\n<h2 class=\"font_2\" style=\"font-size:17px; text-align:center\"><span style=\"font-size:17px\"><span style=\"font-weight:normal\"><span style=\"font-family:brandon-grot-w01-light,sans-serif\">SPRING/SUMMER 2021</span></span></span></h2>",
          "skin": "WRichTextNewSkin",
          "heightFromStructure": 62,
          "widthFromStructure": 980
        },
        "comp-kk5jd9u5": {
          "images": [
            {
              "quality": {},
              "id": "dataItem-kkpd1m01",
              "link": {},
              "data-anchor": {},
              "title": "",
              "type": "Image",
              "uri": "ad3404_075b2a3c51c94d98acaf0f3b29179f14~mv2.jpg",
              "alt": "",
              "width": 1000,
              "height": 1500
            },
            {
              "quality": {},
              "id": "dataItem-kkpd1m14",
              "link": {},
              "data-anchor": {},
              "title": "",
              "type": "Image",
              "uri": "ad3404_59a961932d8845f1852a3fbc4087bf02~mv2.jpg",
              "alt": "",
              "width": 1000,
              "height": 1500
            },
            {
              "quality": {},
              "id": "dataItem-kkpd1m141",
              "link": {},
              "data-anchor": {},
              "title": "",
              "type": "Image",
              "uri": "ad3404_b659c90d3fa64831a282ee2a20f4ab7b~mv2.jpg",
              "alt": "",
              "width": 1000,
              "height": 1500
            },
            {
              "quality": {},
              "id": "dataItem-kkpd1m15",
              "link": {},
              "data-anchor": {},
              "title": "",
              "type": "Image",
              "uri": "ad3404_aa4fab496a564aa9ad2ad03267dd9380~mv2.jpg",
              "alt": "",
              "width": 1000,
              "height": 1500
            },
            {
              "quality": {},
              "id": "dataItem-kkpd1m151",
              "link": {},
              "data-anchor": {},
              "title": "",
              "type": "Image",
              "uri": "ad3404_42864fcda2854fdcaf9354ae1a3ca39d~mv2.jpg",
              "alt": "",
              "width": 1000,
              "height": 1500
            },
            {
              "quality": {},
              "id": "dataItem-kkpd1m152",
              "link": {},
              "data-anchor": {},
              "title": "",
              "type": "Image",
              "uri": "ad3404_b18b16b548b9438685523f8a24a264ba~mv2.jpg",
              "alt": "",
              "width": 1000,
              "height": 1500
            }
          ],
          "mainPageId": "mainPage",
          "quality": {},
          "compProps": {
            "type": "ThumbnailsProperties",
            "metaData": {
              "schemaVersion": "1.0",
              "autoGenerated": false
            },
            "id": "propItem-kk5jd9ub",
            "font": "arial",
            "cropAndFitStage": "fit",
            "componentScale": "16:9",
            "margin": 15,
            "textMode": "noText",
            "arrowMode": true,
            "alignText": "center",
            "autoplayInterval": 3.6,
            "autoplay": true,
            "transDuration": 1,
            "transition": "crossFade",
            "thumbnailsGravity": "bottom",
            "galleryImageOnClickAction": "zoomMode"
          },
          "url": "https://static.parastorage.com/services/santa/1.11596.0/node_modules/santa-galleries/target/Thumbnails/Thumbnails.html?compId=comp-kk5jd9u5&deviceType=desktop&locale=it&viewMode=site",
          "compStyles": {
            "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "alphaTextColor": "1",
            "descriptionColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "alphaDescriptionColor": "1",
            "textBackgroundColor": "#2F2E2E",
            "alphaTextBackgroundColor": "0.6"
          },
          "currentIndex": 0
        },
        "pageBackground_kfrfp": {
          "fillLayers": {
            "containerId": "pageBackground_kfrfp",
            "hasBgFullscreenScrollEffect": false,
            "shouldRenderUnderlay": true,
            "shouldPadMedia": false
          },
          "isMediaPositionOverride": false,
          "mediaHeightOverrideType": ""
        },
        "Containerkfrfp": {
          "meshProps": {
            "wedges": [],
            "rotatedComponents": [
              "comp-kk5jd9tm"
            ],
            "fixedComponents": []
          }
        }
      }}}}
```

````
comp-kk...
``` постоянно меняется название еще, но думаю это не критично
````

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/220553

Comment: У автора одинаковые значения, у меня разные. Чтобы не путать вас, я прикреплю json. Мне нужно получить массив `images`

Comment: Методика получения C# кода та же, что описана в прилинкованном ответе.

Comment: Вы спросили, что делать с названиями - я вам дал ответ - используйте словарь, а из него уже вытаскивайте все, что хотите. То есть самое банальное: `public RenderCompProps CompProps { get; set; }` меняете на `public Dictionary<string, CompKk5Jd9U5> CompProps {get;set;}`, далее `...CompProps["comp-kk5jd9u5"]` (или по индексу через `ElementAt()`), все, "грязно", но получите то, что хотите.

Comment: Вы можете десереализовать в `Dictionary<string, object>`, затем взять 2 элемент и забрать из него данные. Но я бы отрубил палец по самое плечо разработчику, который придумал такую структуру данных.

Comment: @aepot вы еще не видели html сайта) https://www.bacimilano.com/collezione

Comment: Еще можно распарсить динамически конечным автоматом через JObject/JToken, но это не модно, хоть и гарантированно решит задачу.

Comment: Ну я сейчас вашими 2умя способами попробую. Насчет обджекта думал, но не уверен, что под тип приведется

Comment: В `System.Text.Json` можно любой мусор разобрать руками с помощью `Utf8JsonReader` быстро и эффективно, в Json.NET для этого используют например десереализацию в `object` или (прости господи) `dynamic`.

Comment: Тип не приведется. Хотя можно этот обджект обратно сереализовать в строку и потом уже десереализовать в тип (ещё раз перекрестился).

Comment: Спасибо, проверил оба способа, помогли