# Объединить данные из json

Tags: c#, json, алгоритм, классы

Всем привет!

Я совсем недавно начал тесно работать с JSON. И у меня возникла следующая ситуация: Я получаю JSON через REST запрос. В нем есть узел, содержащий большое количество полей, примерно вот так:

```
[{
"analytics":
{
    "A1":12,
    "A2":41,
    "A3":1,
    "A4":18,
    "B1":543150.77,
    "B2":1766437.1800,
    "B5":1193733.91,
    "C2":45667390.7700,
    "C6":1,
    "C7":4,
}}]
```

Это какие-то показатели компании, типо прибыли, количества работников и т.п.

ВЫЖНО: Это не все атрибуты. Вообще в каждой из групп (А, В, С. Названия выдуманные для упрощения, на самом деле атрибуты имеют другие названия) может быть до 10 показателей. Но из-за того, что у определенной компании может не быть каких-то показателей, они не возвращаются.

Я десериализую этот josn с помощью класса:

```
    public class Analytics
    {
        
        public int A1 { get; set; }
        public int A2 { get; set; } //Продолжаю до A10...
        public int B1 { get; set; }
        public int B2 { get; set; }//Продолжаю до B10...
        public int С1 { get; set; }
        public int С2 { get; set; }//Продолжаю до C10...

    }
```

И тут мне нужно придумать алгоритм: Если хоть один показатель из группы (то есть из всех атрибутов , например, А) имеет нулевое значение, то проводим определенные действия. Для нас сейчас не важно какие.

**Так вот. Как мне эти группы сгруппировать между собой? Ну то есть, как мне сначала обработать только показатели А?**

О чем я уже думал:

1. Десериализовать без класса. По типу Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
   ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)jObject["A1"]).Value ... Но особой разницы с классами я не вижу
2. Добавлять поля класса в какую-нибудь коллекцию. И потом пробегать по этой коллекции и проверять значение каждого элемента. Да, вариант может и рабочий. Можно проверять поле на null и если оно не null, то добавлять в коллекцию. Но может есть более простой и быстрый вариант?
3. Сделать отдельные классы для каждой группы. Вот тут, честно, не знаю. Я же десериализую json с помощью класса, а если этот класс разбить на несколько, то он нифига не десериализуется (наверно). Если десериализовать так, как я описал в п.1, а потом значение вставлять в поле класса... Тоже как-то глупо, во-первых, это не красиво, во-вторых, я же не знаю какие показатели мне были переданы, а какие нет. Я буду обращаться ...jObject["A1"]).Value, а этого A1 и нет вовсе. И всё свалится(

В общем, вроде, все просто, но в голову адекватное решение уже сутки не приходит.
Кстати, я могу сделать, чтоб вместо json возвращался xml, но есть ли разница...

P.S: Если кому интересно, как выглядит реальные json или, если вы вдруг предложите разделить по имени, то вот реальные названия атрибутов и это далеко не все:

```
    "q2001":12,
    "q2002":41,
    "q2003":1,
    "q2004":18,
    "s2001":543150.77,
    "s2002":1766437.1800,
    "s2003":1193733.91,
    "s2004":45667390.7700,
    "q2011":1,
    "q2012":4,
    "q2013":13,
    "q2014":6,
    "q2015":5,
    "q2016":1,
    "q2017":1,
    "q2018":2,
    "q2019":5,
    "s2011":22553,
    "s2012":107240.2400,
    "s2013":903121.5200,
    "s2014":94564.3800,
    "s2015":164940.1000,
    "s2016":22553,
    "s2017":24500,
    "s2018":211863.39,
    "s2019":94564.38,
    "q2023":8,
    "q2024":1,
    "q2025":7,
    "s2023":1252206.9100,
    "s2024":500001.00,
    "s2025":42721448.95,
    "q2034":17,
    "q2035":4,
    "s2034":1397505.1600,
    "s2035":2132029.4500,
    "q4002":173,
    "s4002":40119208.62,
    "q4003":3342,
    "s4003":870402241.65,
    "q6001":2020,
    "m6002":true,
    "s6003":14099376000,
    "s6004":16501452000,
    "s6005":5019623000,
    "s6006":6384222000,
    "s6007":796847000,
    "s6008":2269340000,
    "d6014":2020,
    "e6014":"AAA",
    "q7007":50,
    "q7009":114,
    "d7010":"2021-11-26",
    "q7017":22,
    "q7018":1,
    "q7019":3,
    "q7020":2,
    "q7021":8,
    "q8001":5,
    "q9001":50,
    "q1102":1
```

Comment: `Dictionary<string, object> data = JsonSerializer.Deserealize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data.Where(d => d.Key.StartsWith("q")).Select(pair => pair.Key + "=" + pair.Value)));`

Comment: Вы только навели путаницы с этими реальными-нереальными названиями. Можно было просто показать 1 раз максимально приближенный к реальности пример данных и объяснить, что нужно сделать. Ваше решение - десереализация в словарь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/220553

Answer (score 1):

На основе словаря по ответу *aepot*

```
static string _pattern = "([a-zA-Z])";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"{""q2001"":""12"",""a2002"":""null"",""a2003"":""1""}";
    Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

    var blackListGroup = GetBlackList(values);
    Console.WriteLine($"Count blocked groups: {blackListGroup.Count}");
    blackListGroup.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static List<string> GetBlackList(Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
    Regex regex = new(_pattern);
    HashSet<string> blackList = new();
    foreach (var x in values)
    {
        var match = regex.Match(x.Key);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            //Или любая ваша проверка double.TryParse, int.Parse
            if (x.Value == "null")
            {
                blackList.Add(match.Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Regex error with {x}");
        }
    }

    return blackList.ToList();
}
```

[Покликать](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kXiZNo)