# Как мне инициализировать json где параметры меняются?

Tags: c#, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, я получаю такой Json как мне его инициализировать? при том что объектов "test" может быть 10 и более, и где-то есть test1 где-то нету

```
{
   "test":{
      "test1":"string",
      "test2":"int",
      "test3":"Boolean"
   },
   "test":{
      "test1":"string",
      "test4":"Double"
   }
}
internal sealed class TestContainer 
{ 
     public string test1{ get; set; } 
     public int test2{ get; set; } 
     public Boolean test3{ get; set; } 
     public Double test4{ get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/220553

Comment: я так и сделала, но когда я прошу выдать json[1].test4 мне говорит что значение null

Comment: internal sealed class TestContainer
    {
        public string test1{ get; set; }
        public int test2{ get; set; }
        public Boolean test3{ get; set; }
        public Double test4{ get; set; }
    }

Comment: Я не вижу, чтоб вы сделали "так". По ссылке, что я дал, сказано "используйте Dictionary", где он в вашем коде?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, object>`, остальное зависит от используемого сериализатора.