# Парсинг JSON массива ключ-значение?

Tags: c#, json

Есть json, состоящий из массива пар ключ-значение.
Пример:

```
[
{“1”: “value1”},
{“4”: “value2”},
{“10”: “value32”},
….
]
```

Обычно я использую онлайн генераторы классов для стерилизации из json, но генератор расценивает ключ как имя поля (например, 1), а ведь неизвестно, что будет в массиве, какие там ключи, а мне нужно вытаскивать и значения, и ключи.

Comment: Вы через цикл проходили?

Comment: попробуйте перезаписать данные с помощью цикла и добавить ключ к нему n+ n+ n+

Comment: Нет, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>, а класс генерирую через онлайн сервисы. Я действительно новичок в этом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/220553