# Найти строку и вернуться к предыдущему значению c#

Tags: c#

у нас есть файл ( +- 850 строк) формата vdf:

```
"users"
{
    "76561198971110872"
    {
        "AccountName"       "string1"
        "PersonaName"       "nick"
        "RememberPassword"      "1"
        "WantsOfflineMode"      "0"
        "SkipOfflineModeWarning"        "0"
        "AllowAutoLogin"        "1"
        "MostRecent"        "1"
        "Timestamp"     "1657315226"
    }
    "76561199256632399"
    {
        "AccountName"       "string2"
        "PersonaName"       "nick"
        "RememberPassword"      "0"
        "WantsOfflineMode"      "0"
        "SkipOfflineModeWarning"        "0"
        "AllowAutoLogin"        "1"
        "MostRecent"        "0"
        "Timestamp"     "1657313715"
    }
    "76561199264398742"
    {
        "AccountName"       "string3"
        "PersonaName"       "nick"
        "RememberPassword"      "1"
        "WantsOfflineMode"      "0"
        "SkipOfflineModeWarning"        "0"
        "AllowAutoLogin"        "1"
        "MostRecent"        "0"
        "Timestamp"     "1657102771"
    }
}
```

---

Мне нужно получить это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, эти цифры мне не известны, мне известно только "AccountName"

Вопрос - Как получить те цифры?

Буду рад ответить на встречные вопросы )

Comment: Если формат стандартизирован, значит для него есть готовые решения, стоит их найти, а не изобретать велосипед, например [Gameloop.Vdf](https://github.com/shravan2x/Gameloop.Vdf).

Comment: Неплохо в целом, почему-то я когда искал не мог найти этого. Спасибо

Comment: Самый первый результат из NuGet по запросу `Vdf`, может есть и лучше, не знаю, не искал.

Comment: Но, все равно как получить те цифры? Я не столько прошареный как большинство людей которые отвечают на вопросы.

Comment: Для начала, почитать документацию к библиотеке, увидите там то, что она по умолчанию основана на `dynamic`, что не есть хорошо, а для нормальной десериализации нужно использовать `.ToJson().ToObject<SteamModel>();`, ну а какой тип - это уже читайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/220553).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставил NuGet пакет **Gameloop.Vdf**, скопировал ваши данные в файл, написал вот такой код:

```
using Gameloop.Vdf;
using Gameloop.Vdf.Linq;
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    VProperty users = VdfConvert.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText("users.vdf"));

    string name = "string2";
    VProperty user = users.Value
        .OfType<VProperty>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value["AccountName"].Value<string>() == name);
    string key = user?.Key ?? "key not found";
    Console.WriteLine(key);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Получил вот такой вывод в консоль

```
76561199256632399
```

Comment: О снова вы, здравствуйте! ;D Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Снова вас благодарю! Большое спасибо, вы как бог только на земле.