# Десериализовать json

Tags: c#, json

Имеется `json` файл, который содержит кандзи(иероглифы) и выглядит примерно так:

```
{
"柩": {
    "strokes": 9,
    "grade": null,
    "freq": null,
    "jlpt_old": null,
    "jlpt_new": null,
    "meanings": [ "Bier", "Coffin" ],
    "readings_on": [ "きゅう", "ぐ" ],
    "readings_kun": [ "ひちぎ", "ひつぎ" ],
    "wk_level": null,
    "wk_meanings": null,
    "wk_readings_on": null,
    "wk_readings_kun": null,
    "wk_radicals": null
},
"枸": {
    "strokes": 9,
    "grade": null,
    "freq": null,
    "jlpt_old": null,
    "jlpt_new": null,
    "meanings": [ "Quince Tree" ],
    "readings_on": [ "く", "こう" ],
    "readings_kun": [],
    "wk_level": null,
    "wk_meanings": null,
    "wk_readings_on": null,
    "wk_readings_kun": null,
    "wk_radicals": null
}...
```

}

Проблема в том, что если я в `Visual Studio` при помощи `Paste Special` создаю класс, то создаётся два отдельных класса:

```
public class Rootobject
{ 
    public 柩 柩 { get; set; }
    public 枸 枸 { get; set; }
}

public class 柩
{ 
    public int strokes { get; set; }
    public object grade { get; set; }
    public object freq { get; set; }
    public object jlpt_old { get; set; }
    public object jlpt_new { get; set; }
    public string[] meanings { get; set; }
    public string[] readings_on { get; set; }
    public string[] readings_kun { get; set; }
    public object wk_level { get; set; }
    public object wk_meanings { get; set; }
    public object wk_readings_on { get; set; }
    public object wk_readings_kun { get; set; }
    public object wk_radicals { get; set; }
}

public class 枸
{ 
    public int strokes { get; set; }
    public object grade { get; set; }
    public object freq { get; set; }
    public object jlpt_old { get; set; }
    public object jlpt_new { get; set; }
    public string[] meanings { get; set; }
    public string[] readings_on { get; set; }
    public object[] readings_kun { get; set; }
    public object wk_level { get; set; }
    public object wk_meanings { get; set; }
    public object wk_readings_on { get; set; }
    public object wk_readings_kun { get; set; }
    public object wk_radicals { get; set; }
}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы создавался один класс `Kanji`, который имеет все те же поля и само написание иероглифа?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/220553