# Парсинг Json при помощи Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#

Json который получаю

```
{"ts":"7","updates":[{"type":"message_new","object":{"id":6,"date":1526936271,"out":0,"user_id":15075215111,"read_state":0,"title":"","body":"1"},"group_id":166732605}]}
```

Есть классы:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string ts { get; set; }
    public Update[] updates { get; set; }
}

public class Update
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Object _object { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }
}

public class Object
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public int _out { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int read_state { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

Парсим json через `var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);`
Но мне удается достать только `ts` из `Rootobject` хотя мне помимо этого нужно еще `user_id` и `body` из `Object`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: [Вот еще подробный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829577/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json/829611#829611) если вдруг не поняли там :D

Comment: Показали бы JSON, который имеете на входе

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ага, а что конкретно не получается? Структура классов вроде верная. Не забывайте, что updates это массив, элемент из него надо доставать по индексу

Comment: @АндрейNOP пытался через 'updates[1]' и 'updates[2]' вываливается  "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Comment: Логично, там ведь всего один элемент и его индекс 0.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Указал 0 выдало "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: Попробуйте взять набор классов отсюда: https://app.quicktype.io?share=JPE9RNRXj9iwf2oAUIgz

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо помогло