# Как десериализировать Json?

Tags: c#, json

Не могли бы мне помочь) Я тут пытаюсь узнать номер кошелька от киви по токену и для этого мне надо через Json узнать его personalId. То есть я получаю данный ответ. Сейчас в консоле я получаю такой ответ. И из этого всего мне надо как-то достать PersonalId использую RestSharp

```
    public string GetQiwiNumber()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://edge.qiwi.com/person-profile/v1/profile/current");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {Token}");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);\
        string content = response.Content;
        return content;
    }
```

Json код взят от сюда: https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/?http#profile

Я походу чего-то не понимаю.
Всё сделал как мне подсказали в ответе, но всё равно не работает)

```
    public string GetQiwiNumber()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://edge.qiwi.com/person-profile/v1/profile/current");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {Token}");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        JObject j = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
        JToken item = j.SelectToken("$.personId");
        if (item != null)
        {
            string personId = (string)item;
            return personId;
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Минус вопросу за код картинками. Пожалуйста, прикладывайте код текстом!

Comment: @A K, извините, сейчас всё исправлю. Я просто хотел вставить Json код, он вставляется просто в строку из-за этого всё кинул скринами.

Comment: А Json то где???

Comment: @Blackmeser - автор вопроса, видимо, предполагал, что JSON мы можем взять из примера на сайте у Киви. ссылка на сайт в вопросе есть.

Comment: @S.H. Ну тогда тему вопроса следует сменить на: Как десериализировать Json из примера по ссылке на сайт с поломанным (или кривым) дизайном, и неизвестно какой секцией примера. Вопрос из разряда: помоги, но при этом сам пойди, **найди**, да разберись.

Comment: @Blackmeser - я с вами согласен, но я уже нашел и вставил в ответ!

Comment: @Blackmeser - автор в примечании пишет, что первый раз с JSON работает - ну, что поделать, растерялся человек. Может, и не надо его сильно ругать. Меня, например, больше инетерсует, получится ли у автора сделать решение, основанное на "коротком пути" из п.4 моего ответа.

Comment: Снял минус. Вам уже написали ответ, подобных вопросов уже немало на сайте оставлено, поэтому можно поискать более подробные ответы, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829577/213987 - возможно поможет лучше разобраться.

Comment: @ДмитрийСтепанов что именно не работает, вы хотя-бы полученный json предоставьте, если он корректен, то извлечь необходимые вам данные можно очень просто в 2-3 строки: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  Match m = new Regex("\"personId\":(?<name>.*?),").Match(json_string);  return m.Success ? m.Groups["name"].Value.Trim() : "0";

Comment: @Blackmeser - да, кстати, хороший способ, котрый не пришел мне в голову!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала -короткий ответ:

```
        JToken item = j.SelectToken("$.authInfo.personId");
        long personId = (long)item;
```

При этм надодобавить зависимость - Newtonsoft.Json, например, через NuGet: `install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`.

А вообще - есть еще такие способы:

1. Берем данные, указанные на первом скриншоnt - сожержимое JSON. Идём на сервис https://json2csharp.com/. Этот сервис по JSON сгенерирует "приблизительно подходящий" класс C#, в который можно десериализовывать данные. Пусть у Вас в коде этот класс убдет называться AuthInfo
2. Теперь можно сделать простую опреацию по десериализации, что то вроде `AuthInfo answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthInfo>(rawJson);`

В принципе, если бы в вопросе JSON был текстом - то можно было бы всё это проделать, пока я писал ответ.

3. Еще один способ - написать нужный класс `AuthInfo` руками, тогда можно включить туда буквально одно два необходимых поля. Тогда при десериализации всё остальное содерждимое JSON будет просто проигнорировано
4. Дополняю ответ.

Мне в голову пришло, что можно пойти ещё более простым путём:

```
        JObject j = JObject.Parse(rawjson);
        JToken item = j.SelectToken("$.personId");
        if (item != null)
            string peronslId = (string) item;
```

Ну, если я где то ошибся - то, скорее всего, когад переписывал со скриншота имена. А так - должно работать!

5. Дополняю ответ еще раз, после того,к ак автор подправил вопрос:
   Конвертирование JSON'а

   ```
    {
      "authInfo": {
        "boundEmail": "m@ya.ru",
        "ip": "81.210.201.22",
        "lastLoginDate": "2017-07-27T06:51:06.099Z",
        "mobilePinInfo": {
          "lastMobilePinChange": "2017-07-13T11:22:06.099Z",
          "mobilePinUsed": true,
          "nextMobilePinChange": "2017-11-27T06:51:06.099Z"
        },
        "passInfo": {
          "lastPassChange": "2017-07-21T09:25:06.099Z",
          "nextPassChange": "2017-08-21T09:25:06.099Z",
          "passwordUsed": true
        },
        "personId": 79683851815,
        "pinInfo": {
          "pinUsed": true
        },
        "registrationDate": "2017-01-07T16:51:06.100Z"
      },
      "contractInfo": {
        "blocked": false,
        "contractId": 79683851815,
        "creationDate": "2017-01-07T16:51:06.100Z",
        "features": [],
        "identificationInfo": [
          {
            "bankAlias": "QIWI",
            "identificationLevel": "SIMPLE"
          }
        ]
      },
      "userInfo": {
        "defaultPayCurrency": 643,
        "defaultPaySource": 7,
        "email": null,
        "firstTxnId": 10807097143,
        "language": "string",
        "operator": "Beeline",
        "phoneHash": "lgsco87234f0287",
        "promoEnabled": null
      }
    }
   ```

дало нам код класса, опиывающего JSON - объект полностью:

```
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
        public class MobilePinInfo
        {
            public DateTime lastMobilePinChange { get; set; }
            public bool mobilePinUsed { get; set; }
            public DateTime nextMobilePinChange { get; set; }
        }

        public class PassInfo
        {
            public DateTime lastPassChange { get; set; }
            public DateTime nextPassChange { get; set; }
            public bool passwordUsed { get; set; }
        }

        public class PinInfo
        {
            public bool pinUsed { get; set; }
        }

        public class AuthInfo
        {
            public string boundEmail { get; set; }
            public string ip { get; set; }
            public DateTime lastLoginDate { get; set; }
            public MobilePinInfo mobilePinInfo { get; set; }
            public PassInfo passInfo { get; set; }
            public long personId { get; set; }
            public PinInfo pinInfo { get; set; }
            public DateTime registrationDate { get; set; }
        }

        public class IdentificationInfo
        {
            public string bankAlias { get; set; }
            public string identificationLevel { get; set; }
        }

        public class ContractInfo
        {
            public bool blocked { get; set; }
            public long contractId { get; set; }
            public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
            public List<object> features { get; set; }
            public List<IdentificationInfo> identificationInfo { get; set; }
        }

        public class UserInfo
        {
            public int defaultPayCurrency { get; set; }
            public int defaultPaySource { get; set; }
            public object email { get; set; }
            public long firstTxnId { get; set; }
            public string language { get; set; }
            public string @operator { get; set; }
            public string phoneHash { get; set; }
            public object promoEnabled { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public AuthInfo authInfo { get; set; }
            public ContractInfo contractInfo { get; set; }
            public UserInfo userInfo { get; set; }
        }
```

И вот - ура-ура- в AuthInfo мы видим требуемый personId.

Но я настаиваю, что более короткий способ, описанный в пункте 4 - лучше

Успехов!

Comment: здравствуйте. Я перехожу на сайт https://json2csharp.com/ вставляю код он мне кидает ошибку. И дополнение почему-то не работает, хотя всё верно. Я вопрос изменил. С Json работаю впервые и ещё не знаю как всё работает)

Comment: Ошибка - потому, что формально приведенный у киви пример - с ошибкой: в json не бывает многоточий. Нужно вырезать многолочие из приведенной у них портянки - тогда конвертирование сработает

Comment: я изменил вопрос)

Comment: @ДмитрийСтепанов - там надо было правильный путь прописать. Посмотрите начало ответа, я его поправил

Comment: разобрался, всё работает. Спасибо вам большое